# Finding whether element entering in a list is duplicate or unique, while the program is running

Tags: python

so, I came across this question, where I have to create a list, take the elements as input from the user. After doing so, I have to check whether the elements entered by the user are 'Unique' or 'Duplicate', and this has to be done while the program is running. i.e if the input entered is duplicate, then I have to terminate the program then and there, otherwise proceed.

I have written the following code (Python):

```
list = []
num = int(input('enter no. of elements in list: '))

for i in range(0,num):
    q = int(input('element %d: '%(i+1)))
    list.append(q)
    
print(list)
cnt = 0

for i in range(0,num):
    if(list[i]==q):
        cnt = cnt+1
        if(cnt>1):
            print('Duplicate')
    
    else:
        cnt = cnt+0
        if(cnt==0):
            print('Unique')
            
print('\nProgram Terminated!')
```

The thing is that, I know that I might have to use the break statement in the loop where I check whether the values are equal, but I somehow can't place it correctly.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check each time the user puts in a new element, i think this is the solution to your question:

```
list = []
num = int(input('enter no. of elements in list: '))

for i in range(0, num):
   q = int(input('element %d: ' % (i+1)))
   if q not in list:
       print('Unique')
       list.append(q)
   else:
      print('Duplicate')
      break

print(list)
print('\nProgram Terminated!')
```